# jqGrid unexpectedly changing format of data source

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jqgrid

For some reason if I give my jqGrid JSON source data in the format of this:

```
[
  { "Filter": { "UserID": 12, "FirstName": "Harry", "LastName": "Alfred", "FullName": "Harry Alfred", "Initials": "HA" }, "Count": 5, "OtherInfo": 29 },
  { "Filter": { "UserID": 2, "FirstName": "Larry", "LastName": "Anderson", "FullName": "Larry Anderson", "Initials": "LA" }, "Count": 3, "OtherInfo": 23 },
  { "Filter": { "UserID": 4, "FirstName": "Allen", "LastName": "Quayle", "FullName": "Allen Quayle", "Initials": "AQ" }, "Count": 4, "OtherInfo": 24 },
  { "Filter": { "UserID": 5, "FirstName": "Todd", "LastName": "Stevens", "FullName": "Todd Stevens", "Initials": "TS" }, "Count": 2, "OtherInfo": 59 },
  { "Filter": { "UserID": 6, "FirstName": "Cathy", "LastName": "Smith", "FullName": "Cathy Smith", "Initials": "CS" }, "Count": 6, "OtherInfo": 48 }
]
```

It changes it to this which is returned when I try accessing the data via the jqGrid("getGridParam", "data") function:

```
[
  {"Filter.UserID":12,"Filter.FullName":"Harry Alfred","Count":5,"OtherInfo":29,"_id_":"12"},
  {"Filter.UserID":2,"Filter.FullName":"Larry Anderson","Count":3,"OtherInfo":23,"_id_":"2"},
  {"Filter.UserID":4,"Filter.FullName":"Allen Quayle","Count":4,"OtherInfo":24,"_id_":"4"},
  {"Filter.UserID":5,"Filter.FullName":"Todd Stevens","Count":2,"OtherInfo":59,"_id_":"5"},
  {"Filter.UserID":6,"Filter.FullName":"Cathy Smith","Count":6,"OtherInfo":48,"_id_":"6"}
]
```

And of course, this screws up my custom column formatter functions that need to access the rowObject properties.

For example, given the source JSON, in my custom column formatter function, I should be able access the rowObject.Filter.LastName property. And sure enough, I am able to do so when the grid is first displayed.

However, if I try to sort a column, I get a javascript error thrown by my custom formatter function saying "Cannot read property LastName of undefined", which is caused by the auto-reformatting applied by jqGrid to the source data.

What's going on and how can I stop jqGrid from doing this?

Edit:

FYI, I'm using jqGrid 5.0.0, at least according to the .js file's comments, which looks like this:

```
* jqGrid  5.0.0  
* Copyright (c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com 
*  License: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334
```

And which I downloaded from here a while back: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 (although it looks like v5.1 was recently released).  Also here's the full (stripped-down) source so folks can see what I'm doing.:

```
<table id="gridTest"></table>
<div id="gridPagerTest"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#gridTest").jqGrid({
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: [
              { "Filter": { "UserID": 12, "FirstName": "Harry", "LastName": "Alfred", "FullName": "Harry Alfred", "Initials": "HA" }, "Count": 5, "OtherInfo": 29 },
              { "Filter": { "UserID": 2, "FirstName": "Larry", "LastName": "Anderson", "FullName": "Larry Anderson", "Initials": "LA" }, "Count": 3, "OtherInfo": 23 },
              { "Filter": { "UserID": 4, "FirstName": "Allen", "LastName": "Quayle", "FullName": "Allen Quayle", "Initials": "AQ" }, "Count": 4, "OtherInfo": 24 },
              { "Filter": { "UserID": 5, "FirstName": "Todd", "LastName": "Stevens", "FullName": "Todd Stevens", "Initials": "TS" }, "Count": 2, "OtherInfo": 59 },
              { "Filter": { "UserID": 6, "FirstName": "Cathy", "LastName": "Smith", "FullName": "Cathy Smith", "Initials": "CS" }, "Count": 6, "OtherInfo": 48 }
            ],
            styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
            colModel: [
                { label: 'UserID', name: 'Filter.UserID', key: true, hidden: true },
                { label: 'LastName', name: 'Filter.LastName', hidden: true },
                { label: 'User', name: 'Filter.FullName', index: "Filter.LastName", width: 250, formatter: userNameFormatter },
                { label: 'Count', name: 'Count', index: "Count", width: 200 },
                { label: 'OtherInfo', name: 'OtherInfo', index: "OtherInfo", width: 200 },
            ],
            page: 1,
            sortname: "Filter.LastName",
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            rowNum: 10,
            pager: "#gridPagerTest"
        });
    });

    function userNameFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return "<a href=\"SomePage?DisplayName=" + encodeURIComponent(rowObject.Filter.LastName) + "&UserID=" + rowObject.Filter.UserID + "\">" + cellvalue + "</a>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The original format of JSON data is very good. The problem only: which columns you want to display? Do you use `loadonce: true` option? Which version of jqGrid you use and from, which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? I develop free jqGrid fork and all things which you described can be implemented with the fork. You need just describe exactly what you need and post some JavaScript code which you tried. I can try to modify it to make it working.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks Oleg, I've updated my post to include the version as well as the complete (stripped-down) source showing how I'm using it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *What `datatype` you use in your **real application**? `datatype: "json"`, `datatype: "local"` or really `datatype: "jsonstring"`?* If you want I can fix your code by usage my fork: free jqGrid. It have the same possibilities which you need, but a little more: `additionalProperties` option which allows you to solve your problem.

Comment: Look at https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/oxejLgx4/2/

Comment: By the way, Guriddo, which you loaded have open source, but it can't use for free. See the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Moreover the licence of the code is changed too. It was started with 4.7.1 version, see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438). After the post I made the fork of 4.7 version and started the development myself. I continue provide it for free under MIT/GPL-licenses, like old versions of jqGrid. Thus you have choice either to use my fork free jqGrid with many new featured described in readmes and wiki or to pay and use commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS

Comment: @Oleg Thanks Oleg, for this particular grid I was using `datatype: "jsonstring"`.  It's strange because I've used virtually the same jqGrid/settings/code elsewhere and haven't run into this problem so I was thrown for a loop.  Is there no way to prevent the version of jqGrid I'm using from rearranging the JSON?  I'll take a look at your fork though, thanks for the info.

Comment: The feature `additionalProperties` it's one from many **new** features which I implemented. The features not exist in jqGrid 4.7 and I don't know whether close features were implemented in Guriddo.